# Apache HIVE Jobs as Web service

Tags: hive

I would like to expose HIVE as web service, so that my PHP programs can invoke the web service to show the output in UI. i am not sure how to do this in HIVE.

Comment: Do you want to show the progress of Hive jobs already running or submit a request and wait for the result? If it's the second, you are barking at the wrong tree. Hive requests generate MapReduce jobs, sometimes several per request. It easily takes 30 sec to set up and run a MapReduce job even if it processes a single row of data.

Comment: Thanks Olaf.

My requirement is to access the Hive queries from PHP. I would like to know if the Hive can be accessed through web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a JDBC driver for Hive. It supports only a subset of JDBC API and SQL syntax. These limitations are defined by the capabilities of Hive. Hive is much better suited for batch commands, for example filter a large subset of an enormous set of data, possibly joining with other Hive tables. Nevertheless, using JDBC you can conceivably access Hive data via web services. You might consider creating asynchronous web services. If you are going to access Hive in synchronous web service calls, make sure your timeouts are large enough to accommodate times needed to run Hive commands.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I am also looking at HBase as Hive StorageHandler.                              All the data analysis is performed offline suing Hive and the final data is stored in HBase.Application can query the HBase to display the data in UI. Is there any better approach.

Comment: @Kartik: I've seen a memory cache installed between HBase and the web UI.